# RuntimeError: `set_session` is not available when using TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have an application that uses Keras and Tensorflow 2.0. It seems to work until I try to set the number of inter and intra op threads. Here's how it's done.

```
from keras import backend as K
# some irrelevant stuff

import tensorflow as tf

session_conf = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(inter_op_parallelism_threads=int(os.environ['NUM_INTER_THREADS']),
    intra_op_parallelism_threads=int(os.environ['NUM_INTRA_THREADS']))
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
K.set_session(sess) #this is where it blows up.
```

So far, looking around, I haven't found anything that would suggest this is wrong. I am indeed setting the NUM_INTER_THREADS and NUM_INTRA_THREADS environment variables (I have a print that outputs them and they are indeed what I've set them too).

Version Info:

tensorflow 2.1.0

tensorflow-base 2.1.0

tensorflow-estimator 2.1.0

keras 2.3.1

keras-applications 1.0.8

keras-base  2.3.1

keras-preprocessing 1.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(
    session
)
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/keras/backend/set_session

On tensorflow 2 keras its in tensorflow, so you ve to use it like tf.compat.v1.keras

Comment: Can u check it as solved?I cant post my issue unitl i resolve another